# How to make a single user's calendar private?

Tags: permissions, powershell, calendar, exchange-2010

We're using Exchange 2010. A few weeks ago I used the following PowerShell script to give everyone access to everyone's calendars:

```
$users = Get-mailbox
$users | ForEach-Object {Set-MailboxFolderPermission $_":\Calendar" -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer}
```

However, I would now like to make one user's calendar private, so that the user themselves can see their own calendar, but no one else can. Is there a script for this? Or a method through the GUI?

Comment: Wouldn't [`Remove-MailboxFolderPermission`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351181(v=exchg.141).aspx) work? I've no way to test this, but from reading the docs it seems something like the following should do the job: `Get-MailUser | Where-Object { $_.Identity -ne "user@company" } | ForEach-Object { Remove-MailboxFolderPermission user@company:\Calendar -User $_.Identity }`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Only just saw this, and it probably would have worked, not sure why I din't consider it... All i did was ammend the first line to only find the user in question then changed the second line from "Reviewer" to "None" and it seems to have done the trick!

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed. However, if I'm reading the docs for [`Set-MailboxFolderPermission`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff522363(v=exchg.141).aspx) correctly, "None" doesn't actually mean no permissions at all, it means the user will be able to view the folder, just not any items within it. If that's fine for your purposes, then you're set, but if not, you'll probably have to use `Remove-MailboxFolderPermission`.

Comment: Hmmm... It seemed to have worked, but better safe than sorry I've run Set-MailboxFolderPermission. Thanks again, really appreciate your help! :-)

Comment: Also, would really like to vote up on your answer but not sure if I can 'cause you've put it down as a comment? If there's a way to let me know! Otherwise if you want to post it as an answer I'll vote it up!

Comment: I've posted my proposed solution as an answer.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid... You need 15 rep to vote up and I only have 11... So sorry! When i get my rep up I'll vote up honest!

Comment: No problem :) If you want, you can [post your own solution as an answer as well](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and I'll be happy to give it an upvote. That should push you past 15 rep. More importantly, though, you should mark an answer as accepted (whether mine, or your own if you decide to post it), for the benefit of others who might have the same problem and find this question.

Comment: Hey thanks for that much appreciated again! I've ticked your answer as accepted and added mine below! Sorry, I know I'm a bit of a SuperUser noob haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cmdlet for removing permissions is [`Remove-MailboxFolderPermission`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351181%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx). So something like the following should work (though I've no way to actually test it):

```
Get-MailUser |
Where-Object { $_.Identity -ne "user@company" } |
ForEach-Object { Remove-MailboxFolderPermission user@company:\Calendar -User $_.Identity }
```

I've split it up to several lines for clarity, but you can enter it as a one-liner. Replace "user@company" with the user whose mailbox you wish to make private.

Answer (score 1):

I amended the first line to only find the user in question then changed the second line from "Reviewer" to "None" and it seems to have done the trick!

But better safe than sorry so I've also done as suggested by Indrek above.